# Error when using position = "fill" in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, fill

I am working to analyse some data from the BRFSS13 dataset and have come acropper when trying to adjust my graph.

I have used the following code to create my tibble:

```
vets <- select(brfss2013, veteran3, sex, renthom1, children)
vetTib <- vets %>%
filter(!is.na(veteran3)) %>%
filter(!is.na(renthom1)) %>%
filter(!is.na(children)) %>%
group_by(sex, veteran3, renthom1) %>%
mutate(count = n())
```

So far, so good. I've then used ggplot to create a graph showing how gender affects home owner status.

```
vetTib %>%
ggplot(aes(x = sex, y= count, fill = renthom1)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But the disparity in volume of female/male data is making the resultant graph rather unhelpful. In my infinite wisdom I thought that the following would fix the issue by showing the differences as proportions rather than absolute values:

```
vetTib %>%
ggplot(aes(x = sex, y= count, fill = renthom1)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = “fill”)
```

But unfortunately this gives me the following:

```
Error: unexpected input in:
"    ggplot(aes(x = sex, y= count, fill = renthom1)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = “"
```

I have no idea where I've gone wrong! I've used geom_bar with position = "fill" lots of times before so am really confused at why it won't do what it is supposed to!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Steph

Comment: `fill` has different quotes, maybe this is the problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, please could you elaborate?

Comment: `“fill”` is not the same as `"fill"`. The quotes ("") are different.

Comment: Copy and try this: `vetTib %>%
ggplot(aes(x = sex, y= count, fill = renthom1)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill")`

Comment: Thanks @RiccardoLavelli That did it!